# changing sharepoint column name using xslt

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, xslt, customization

I want to change the display name of "Item child count" on my lists. The "only" way I could find untill now is through xslt(no, that particular column cannot be found in the document library columns for me to edit), but being a beginer on the matter I'm finding it a bit hard to master/use.

A small example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="ItemChildCount" mode="body" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@name]='ItemChildCount'">
            <xsl:attribute name="displayname">Elementi</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: I think it would be easier if you provided an example of what you have now and what you would expect to get when you were done

Comment: Does this not apply? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5050/how-to-rename-the-column-item-child-count-in-a-list-sharepoint

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. That would be the correct procedure with almost every other column but this one doesn't appear in there.

Comment: Iris: I second @woody -- Could you, please edit the question and provide the source XML document and the exact wanted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to change the column name. Opening the view with sharepoint designer is entirely possible to change the name of the column. The xsl code will be added to the page automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and followup comment correctly, then the reason you can't find the ItemChildCount is because it's not a data field in your dataview web part or dataform web part.

If you edit the source for your DVWP/DFWP, you should see a  element. If you don't see the attribute listed, you can add it by appending `;@ItemChildCount,Item Child Count`. After you do that, this attribute will be available for your use.